# Problem to convert OffsetDateTime to LocalDateTime in MapStruct

Tags: java, spring-boot, quarkus, mapstruct

I have a DTO class that has an attribute of type OffsetDateTime and another class with the attribute LocalDateTime but at test time it returns the error below:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-07-19T16:21:33.3145924' could not be parsed at index 2
```

I'm mapping like this:

```
@Mapper
public interface PareInputMapper {

    PareInputMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PareInputMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "data", source = "data")
    DataPareDto toResponse(DataPare domain);

    List<PareDto> toResponseList(List<Pare> domainList);

    default OffsetDateTime map(String value) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(value, formatter);
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
        return zonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime();
    }
}
```

In the DTO class the object is of type OffsetDateTime and in the domain class it is of type LocalDateTime.

Just remembering that these date attributes are inside a list that is in the DataPare and DataDto class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you are getting should be clear. Your problem is a simple Java problem. The is that the String you insert in your value can´t be parsed since it looks different than the pattern the DateFormatter got.
The String you provided looks like the default IsoLocalDateTime Pattern.
You can simply replace

```
default OffsetDateTime map(String value) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(value, formatter);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
    return zonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime();
}
```

with

```
default OffsetDateTime map(String value) {
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(value);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
    zonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime();
}
```

or with

```
default OffsetDateTime map(String value) {
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
    zonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime();
}
```

You mentioned that this only occurs in your test Scenario. I would then assume that your `value` string looks different in your test case.

Comment: That's really what you mentioned. Your approach worked. Thank you very much!